# Side by side with css

Tags: html, css

I aligned my `div` to left but there is something wrong with my aligned div that I don't understand.When I aligned my div I'm seeing they are not aligned correctly..what's wrong with my code ?

[please click to see online demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/wdqQEa)

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

#box {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.otel-list-box {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 47%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hotel-links {
  padding: 15px 15px 18px 25px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hotel-links ul li {
  padding: 7px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.hotel-links ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: color linear 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: color linear 0.4s;
  transition: color linear 0.4s;
}

.otel-list-box .otel-list-content figure img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #faa82b;
  height: 172px;
}

.otel-list-box:nth-child(2n) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">

  <div class="otel-list-box">
  </div>
  <!-- each item-->

  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- each item-->


  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- each item-->


  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- each item-->



  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- each item-->


  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- each item-->
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- each item-->

</div>
```

Comment: Didnt get your question?

Comment: Height of `div` is different, that may be a problem.

Comment: but my each div's height can be different

Comment: @athimohan all float my all div but they look disgusting

Comment: you can use bootstrap for this. it's even recomended

Comment: When making some kind of grid display i would always recommend using some kind of container with colums for left and right. But right now adding `display: flex`, `flex-wrap: wrap` and `justify-content: space-between` to 
`#box` in css kind of cleans up a bit. Try looking in to [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @MihaiT how must be my structure then if I use bootstrap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few solutions to this problem.

1. use FlexBox

add `display:flex` to `#box` ( the container of the boxes ) , and then add `width:calc(50% - 30px)` to the `otel-list-box` . 30px because you will set margin left and right of 15px to each box

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ga545eaz/)

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#box{
  width:960px;
  margin:20px auto;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
  
}
.otel-list-box{
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: calc(50% - 30px);
   margin:0 15px 30px;
}
figure{
      position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.hotel-links {
    padding: 15px 15px 18px 25px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.hotel-links ul li {
    padding: 7px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
.hotel-links ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: color linear 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: color linear 0.4s;
    transition: color linear 0.4s;
}
.otel-list-box .otel-list-content figure img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #faa82b;
    height: 172px;
}
.otel-list-box:nth-child(2n){
}
```

```html
<div id="box">


  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->

  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
</div>
```

2. Using bootstrap , it uses FlexBox but it's better to build your whole HTML structure with bootstrap, it's more responsive and easy to use

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#box{
  width:960px;
  margin:20px auto;

  
}
.otel-list-box{
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
 
}
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}
figure{
      position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.hotel-links {
    padding: 15px 15px 18px 25px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.hotel-links ul li {
    padding: 7px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
.hotel-links ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: color linear 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: color linear 0.4s;
    transition: color linear 0.4s;
}
.otel-list-box .otel-list-content figure img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #faa82b;
    height: 172px;
}
.otel-list-box:nth-child(2n){
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="box" class=" row row-eq-height">


  <div class="otel-list-box col-sm-6">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box col-sm-6">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box col-sm-6">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->

  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box col-sm-6">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box col-sm-6">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  <div class="otel-list-box col-sm-6">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
</div>
```

3. using `display:table` . this is more tricky as you need to insert another div, that wraps 2 `otel-list-box`es

`display:table` on `#box` ; `display:table-row` on `boxRow` and `display:table-cell` on `.otel-list-box`

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#box{
  width:960px;
  margin:20px auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
 display:table;
 
  
}
.otel-list-box{
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: calc(50% - 30px);
   margin:0 15px 30px;
  display:table-cell;
}
.boxRow {
 display:table-row
}
figure{
      position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.hotel-links {
    padding: 15px 15px 18px 25px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.hotel-links ul li {
    padding: 7px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
.hotel-links ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: color linear 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: color linear 0.4s;
    transition: color linear 0.4s;
}
.otel-list-box .otel-list-content figure img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #faa82b;
    height: 172px;
}
.otel-list-box:nth-child(2n){
}
```

```html
<div id="box">

<div class="boxRow">



  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
</div>  
<div class="boxRow">  
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
 
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxRow">
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
 </div>
  
</div>
```

4. using JQ to make cols equal in height + float:left

```js
var otel = $(".otel-list-box"),
    highest = 0;
        $(otel).each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highest){  
                highest = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $(otel).height(highest);
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#box{
  width:960px;
  margin:20px auto;
 
  
}
.otel-list-box{
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: calc(50% - 30px);
   margin:0 15px 30px;
   float:left;
}

figure{
      position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.hotel-links {
    padding: 15px 15px 18px 25px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.hotel-links ul li {
    padding: 7px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
.hotel-links ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: color linear 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: color linear 0.4s;
    transition: color linear 0.4s;
}
.otel-list-box .otel-list-content figure img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #faa82b;
    height: 172px;
}
.otel-list-box:nth-child(2n){
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">

<div class="boxRow">



  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
</div>  
<div class="boxRow">  
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
 
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="boxRow">
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
  <div class="otel-list-box">
    <div class="hotel-list-content">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/300x172/2017-04/otel_anasayfa_YBlzcqup5KUoDQG7CE8o2-cocuk-ucretsiz.png" />
      </figure>
      <div class="hotel-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- each item-->
 </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot but my each div can't be same size for example my first  div has a lot of content but my second div just has a few content then why my second div is same size with first div ?

Comment: wow. i thought you wanted that . so the `white` background is the same height

Comment: then you should use Bootstrap and wrap each 2 boxes ( with class .col-sm-6 ) inside a row so they will stay on separate rows. check here example 
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32363/